# How can I realize a ManyToOne relation using the CrudRepository (Spring Data and thymeleaf )?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am using Spring boot and spring Data (CrudRepository) to persist entity passing by a form, but i have a ManyToOne  relation between Product and StatutProduit (idStatutProduit as a foreign key in Produit entity), the problem that i dont know how to say to the controller  that i have an object that depend to an other object...otherwise i have to create w form with thymeleaf for product class for sure with combo box to load statusProduct.

Produit Class (:

```
public class Produits implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    // @Max(value=?)  @Min(value=?)//if you know range of your decimal fields consider using these annotations to enforce field validation
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "ID_PRODUIT")
    private BigDecimal idProduit;
    @Column(name = "ID_OPERATEUR")
    private BigInteger idOperateur;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 45)
    @Column(name = "CODE")
    private String code;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 45)
    @Column(name = "LIBELLE")
    private String libelle;
    @Column(name = "POIDS")
    private BigInteger poids;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 5)
    @Column(name = "INDICE")
    private String indice;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 10)
    @Column(name = "CREE_PAR")
    private String creePar;
    @Column(name = "DATE_CREATION")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date dateCreation;
    @Size(max = 10)
    @Column(name = "MAJ_PAR")
    private String majPar;
    @Column(name = "DATE_MAJ")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date dateMaj;
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_STATUT_PRODUIT", referencedColumnName = "ID_STATUT_PRODUIT")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private StatutProduits idStatutProduit;
    public Produits(BigDecimal idProduit, String code, String libelle, 
    String indice, String creePar) {
    this.idProduit = idProduit;
    this.code = code;
    this.libelle = libelle;
    this.indice = indice;
    this.creePar = creePar;
}
```

StatusProduct class:

```
public class StatutProduits implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
   fields consider using these annotations to enforce field validation
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "ID_STATUT_PRODUIT")
    private BigDecimal idStatutProduit;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 45)
    @Column(name = "CODE")
    private String code;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 45)
    @Column(name = "LIBELLE")
    private String libelle;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 10)
    @Column(name = "CREE_PAR")
    private String creePar;
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    @Column(name = "DATE_CREATION")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date dateCreation;
    @Size(max = 10)
    @Column(name = "MAJ_PAR")
    private String majPar;
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    @Column(name = "DATE_MAJ")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date dateMaj;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "idStatutProduit")
    private List<Produits> produitsList;

    public StatutProduits() {
    }

    public StatutProduits(BigDecimal idStatutProduit) {
        this.idStatutProduit = idStatutProduit;
    }

    public StatutProduits(BigDecimal idStatutProduit, String code, String libelle, String creePar) {
        this.idStatutProduit = idStatutProduit;
        this.code = code;
        this.libelle = libelle;
        this.creePar = creePar;
    }

    public BigDecimal getIdStatutProduit() {
        return idStatutProduit;
    }

    public void setIdStatutProduit(BigDecimal idStatutProduit) {
        this.idStatutProduit = idStatutProduit;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getLibelle() {
        return libelle;
    }

    public void setLibelle(String libelle) {
        this.libelle = libelle;
    }

    public String getCreePar() {
        return creePar;
    }

    public void setCreePar(String creePar) {
        this.creePar = creePar;
    }

    public Date getDateCreation() {
        return dateCreation;
    }

    public void setDateCreation(Date dateCreation) {
        this.dateCreation = dateCreation;
    }

    public String getMajPar() {
        return majPar;
    }

    public void setMajPar(String majPar) {
        this.majPar = majPar;
    }

    public Date getDateMaj() {
        return dateMaj;
    }

    public void setDateMaj(Date dateMaj) {
        this.dateMaj = dateMaj;
    }

    public List<Produits> getProduitsList() {
        return produitsList;
    }

    public void setProduitsList(List<Produits> produitsList) {
        this.produitsList = produitsList;
    }
```

ProduitService class :

```
@Service
public class ProduitService {

    @Autowired
    private ProduitRepository produitrepository ;

    public void addProduit(Produits p ) {



    }

}
```

Comment: Instead of using `@Column(name = "CREE_PAR")` on every field, I would configure a `NamingStrategy`. Are you using  `Hibernate`?

Comment: yes, but this is not the problem hibernate is working without  a problem.

Comment: I know it's off topic. But it makes your class lots tidier and saves you time [Configure Hibernate Naming Strategy](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/howto-data-access.html#howto-configure-hibernate-naming-strategy).
Setting one property vs. defining `@Column` n-times

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at this page https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/. Here you can see this piece of code:

```
package hello;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource;

@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "people", path = "people")
public interface PersonRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Person, Long> {

    List<Person> findByLastName(@Param("name") String name);

}
```

If you make the repository this way Spring will create the controller and the service to fit your `@Entity`.

Comment: Downvoted because OP specifically asked for a MVC controller, not a REST controller.